# ASP.NET Calendar Not Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding a Calendar to to my application and am having a hard time updating the date.  For some reason when I select a new date the previous date is displayed. So if it starts on the 11th and I select the 13th, the 11th is displayed again when the page reloads and then if I select the 14th after that the 13th will load.

I declare the calendar in the application like this:

```
    <asp:Calendar ID="myCal" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

And then I have this code in page_init:

```
    myCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

And use this in page_load:

```
    String date = myCal.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calendar probably triggers a postback, but the `Page_Load` event occurs before any control events. That means you are loading the "previous" selected value each time in the `Page_Load` method.

You should move your `string date = myCal.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` and its associated usage from the `Page_Load` to the `SelectionChanged` event handler for the calendar control.

So create the following method:

```
protected void myCal_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date = myCal.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    // lblMyLabel.Text = date;
    // Put your code that handles the selected date here.
}
```

And associate it with your calendar:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="myCal" runat="server"
    OnSelectionChanged="myCal_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: It gives me OnSelectionChange is not a valid attribute of element 'Calender'

Comment: @user, I fixed it above. Each of the 'SelectionChange' should be 'SelectionChanged'. That should fix any issue.

Comment: This still does page_load before it changes the value.  Is there any way to change the value before page_load?

Comment: @user, no that is the ASP page lifecycle. It can't be changed. You just need to move your code to the event handler.